# Spring jdbc SQL Bad grammar exception, is the selection columns strict?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

As I am trying to authenticate through database using spring security, i have googled several examples, all of them similar like this queries:

```
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

       users-by-username-query="
          select username,password, enabled 
          from users where username=?" 

       authorities-by-username-query="
          select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur 
          where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " 

    />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

is it wrong if i will change the queries like as following? if not why?

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
          <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select login.name,login.passw from login where login.name=?"
          authorities-by-username-query="select login.name, login.type from login where login.name =?"/>

    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

this my example giving an bad SQL exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alias:

```
users-by-username-query="select login.name username,login.passw password from login where login.name=?"
```

but I think you will need `enabled` too. You can hardcode it to be true in the query if you dont have it in the database.